# dropdownlist selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

This may seem very trivial, I used to know how to do this at one time but for some reason I can't seem to get my head around it this time:

I have two tables: `Hotel` and `HotelRooms`
The `Hotel` table has `HotelID` and other hotel details and the `HotelID` is found in `HotelRooms` with different roomtypes, each roomtype has a description.
One Hotel can have many rooms types.

I have a `DropDownList` that contains `HotelID` and `RoomIDs`. `HotelID` comes from a session variable. `HotelID` is the value for the `DropDownList; but the list displays`RoomType`. 
When`Roomtypes`are selected I want to display a`GridView` with the hotel room details like description, price etc....

I can't do this because the value for my DropDownList is `HotelID` which is mapped to the `Session ID`. How do I get the HotelRoom details from the selected value of the DropDownList, please?

**Update:**

Code for Gridview:

```
        string intResortID = Request.QueryString("intResortID ")
        string strRoomType = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bdsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT tblAvail.dtm, tblResortsRooms.strRoomType, tblResortsRooms.strDescription, tblAvail.intQty, tblAvail.curPrice, tblAvail.intResortID, tblResortsRooms.intWSCode FROM tblAvailable INNER JOIN tblResortsRooms ON tblAvail.intResortID = tblResortsRooms.intResortID AND tblAvail.strRoomType = tblResortsRooms.strRoomType WHERE (tblResortsRooms.curRecRate > 0) AND (tblAvail.intResortID = @intResortID) AND (tblAvail.strRoomType = @strRoomType) AND (tblAvailable.dtm >= { fn CURDATE() }) ORDER BY tblResortsRooms.strRoomType",Con);
        SqlParameter ResID = new SqlParameter("@intResortID", intResortID);
        SqlParameter RoomType = new SqlParameter("@strRoomType", strRoomType);
        sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(ResID);
        sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(RoomType);
```

```
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="strRoomType" 
        DataValueField="intResortID" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [intResortID], [strRoomType] FROM [tblResortsRooms] WHERE ([intResortID] = @intResortID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="intResortID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: can you show us some code at least? ^^

Comment: where and how do you fill your dropdownlist? can you show that?

Comment: Updated again, please see above

Comment: I think you got things wrong. what's the point of having a DataValueField with same values? and if your DataTextField is RoomID are you displaying a list of Room Id's to the user? that is not good. Can you post the tables that you are using along with the column names?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by same values but have updated my question above with the code for the dropdownlist

Comment: OK see your query `SELECT [intResortID], [strRoomType] FROM [tblResortsRooms] WHERE ([intResortID] = @intResortID)` which you use to fill DropDownList2. so basically in this query the returned list will have the same ResortIDs returned. So basically your DataValueField will always have the same IDs. Your tables seems to be not properly normalized. Unless your give the tables involved along with the column names, it is difficult to help with a solution.

Comment: That is the table involved. I don't get what you mean by " Unless your give the tables involved along with the column names, it is difficult to help with a solution."

Comment: Let me know the tables and column names (ResortTable - ID, Name, other columns..... & ResortRooms - ID, Name, othercolumns....... & RoomType - ID, Name, other columns......) and the relationships among them. simple as that. Don't add as comment. Edit the question and post there

Comment: @prashanth t  He already provided the query, that should be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'DropDownList1.SelectedValue' should give you the value for `@intResortID`.
'DropDownList2.SelectedValue' should give you the value for `@strRoomType`.

`DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged` should run the query by [filling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill.aspx) something (like a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx)).
The filled DataTable should be bound to your GridView.

Try something like the following in your `DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged` method:

```
string intResortID = Request.QueryString("intResortID ");
string strRoomType = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bdsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT tblAvail.dtm, tblResortsRooms.strRoomType, tblResortsRooms.strDescription, tblAvail.intQty, tblAvail.curPrice, tblAvail.intResortID, tblResortsRooms.intWSCode FROM tblAvailable INNER JOIN tblResortsRooms ON tblAvail.intResortID = tblResortsRooms.intResortID AND tblAvail.strRoomType = tblResortsRooms.strRoomType WHERE (tblResortsRooms.curRecRate > 0) AND (tblAvail.intResortID = @intResortID) AND (tblAvail.strRoomType = @strRoomType) AND (tblAvailable.dtm >= { fn CURDATE() }) ORDER BY tblResortsRooms.strRoomType", Con);
SqlParameter ResID = new SqlParameter("@intResortID", intResortID);
SqlParameter RoomType = new SqlParameter("@strRoomType", strRoomType);
sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(ResID);
sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(RoomType);
DataTable results = new DataTable();

sdr.Fill(results);

resultsGridView.DataSource = results;   //Assuming resultsGridView is the name of the GridView on your ASPX page.
resultsGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: should my dropdownlist2 have postback on?

Comment: @user1270384 Yes, as long as you want the GridView to update when the user selects an option.

Comment: @user1270384  Cool, have you tried placing a break point in `DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged` to make sure the method is being called?  Also, have you checked that `intResortID` and `strRoomType` are returning the correct values?

Comment: @user1270384 Wait, is `strRoomType` suppose to be the content the user is seeing?  If so then the first two lines should be `string intResortID = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;string strRoomType = DropDownList2.SelectedText;`

Comment: Yes strRoomtype is supposed to be the content the user is seeing and theres no option for Dropdownlist2.selectedtext. Do you mean dropdownlist.selecteditem.text or something like that?

Comment: @user1270384 Yes, something like that.  If you run in the debugger you can check that the values are correct.

Comment: @user1270384 So, did that fix it?

Comment: nope my gridview does not get displayed at all when I do that. There is no error though

Answer (score 2):

Try `SelectedItem.Text` of the dropdownlist.

Comment: I get error object reference not set to instance of an object

Comment: What fields are in the drop down list? HotelID as the DataValueField and RoomID as the DataTextField?

Comment: So to test, are you running the code on OnSelectedIndexChange event of the DropDownList? You should be able to access the DropDownList properties from the sender of the event.

Comment: Yes I am running the code in the selectedindexchange event of the dropdownlist

Comment: It seems like this is the only problem you are having at this stage. Can you post the code for where you are trying to retrieve the value in the event?

Comment: In the event I am calling BindGridView() Which has the code I have placed in my question above. Do you need me to add more code to that? only the databinding to the dataset comes afterwards...

Comment: Personally I would be changing the SQL Statement in the event, but that is the way my gridviews are driven. I am not sure you are able to tap into the correct property of the DropDownList using the asp:ControlParameter

Comment: sorry, accidentally hit enter while posting- read previous post

Comment: Try  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="intResortID" 
                **PropertyName="SelectedItem.Text"** Type="Int32" />

Comment: are you still getting the 'object reference not set to instance of an object' message? try removing the code behind that is setting the datasource of the gridview. by the looks you are setting it in codebehind and in the aspx

Comment: no datasource is only for the dropdownlists, the gridview picks from the codebehind....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a new ID (Primary Key) in your HotelRooms table which uniquely identifies each room. If you had that, you could use that as the value for the dropdown and the problem goes away.

Comment: Well @John My HotelRoom ID is the Primary key along with the ID for the HotelRoom Table but because its my hotelID that is the datafield value and not the hotel Room ID I cannot display anything in my gridview because there is no roomtype coming through

Comment: Instead of the composite primary key, you could add a single id field as a new Primary Key and use this for the value? This relies on the user selecting the hotel first and you then filling the dropdown with the rooms for that hotel.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, i already tried one dropdownlist for the Hotel list and another dropdownlist for the room listing but when I select the roomtype nothing happens with the gridview

Comment: From what I understand there is no single id that uniquely identifies rooms. The unique id comes from a combination of HotelID and RoomID? 

This means you have no way of loading room data from a dropdown because the dropdown only has one value field.

What you need to do is add another field to your room table which is an IDENTITY field and make that the Primary Key. You then use that as the value field in your drop down.

So you have a list of hotels, when select happens you use hotelid to populate another list of rooms which uses the new key as the value field...

Hope that helps...

Comment: Which is why i need the datafield value of resort ID to stay but I also need to pull RoomType from the dropdownlist, isn't there something like selectedindex or something?

Comment: There is SelectedItem.Text as somebody mentioned but I would recommend restructuring the data as suggested if possible rather than reading the text values like this.

Comment: OK I cannot add another field to my table because this is an existing table with data already existent in it. This could cause problems in areas where previous code is written as select *